# Disk is full after a PostgreSQL operation. Now what?

Tags: postgresql

I added a column to a huge table in PostgreSQL. Since the table occupied more than 50% of the free disk space and the operation was running in a transaction, all of the disk space got consumed by the edited rows before the transaction could finish and the operation failed. Now I know how I should do it properly - add the columns and then add their values in batches, but every time I try now, the DB runs out of disk space after a couple of batches, even if I run `VACUUM ANALYZE` between the batches.

In the past, I would run `VACUUM FULL` and get the free space back. However, since version 9.0, the `VACUUM FULL` command works similarly to the `CLUSTER` command and requires some free disk space to finish, which I don't have.

Is there a way to clean up the DB in-place and reclaim the free space?